# Display Gif while waiting for curl_exec to get the response

Tags: javascript, php, curl

This is bugging me for a while

Can we do something like displaying a **gif** or executing a code while we are waiting for the **curl_exec** to get the response?

Or the only way to do it is only via javascript?

Thank you

Comment: you need to use javascript , period

Answer (score 1):

you should do it with jquery or javascript
like this

html--------------------------

```
<html>
<div class="container-fluid" id="register_wait" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0;background-color: #0000005c;display: none;">
     <img src="your_gif_address.gif">
</div>
</html>
```

jquery----------------------------

```
<script>
       $("#register_wait").css('display' , 'block');
      /*your curl_exec or anything you wanna the waiting gif runs for it*/
      /**** after done your work ****/
      $("#register_wait").css('display' , 'none');
</script>
```

I hope it helps you